# How do I make node_gallery image thumbnails retain original proportions?

Tags: 7, media

When I upload an image to a Drupal 7 [node_gallery](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_gallery) gallery, a thumbnail is automatically generated. This is good.

However, the thumbnail is also *cropped* to a square size. This is bad. (But note that the full-sized image is not cropped.)

I want **the thumbnail to retain the original image proportions** (often 2:3 or 3:4), the same as the full-sized image (just smaller), rather than being cropped to a 1:1 format.

How can I do that? Google was distinctly unhelpful in this case, showing me results only for old versions of Drupal, and even then those solutions were mostly for other problems.

Comment: never used this module, but try checking `/admin/config/media/image-styles` perhaps the module has an image style. If so, all you have to do is edit it and change it to your liking.

Comment: @NoSssweat That's it! Editing the `node_gallery_thumbnail` style to replace the "Scale and crop" effect with a "Scale" with the same numbers for width and height did the trick. I didn't even need to re-upload my images. If you want some more rep, feel free to post that as an answer and I'll gladly accept it. (Otherwise I'll post it as a self-answer later, but since you were the one who solved my problem, I figure you deserve the rep. :)) Even better if you also include how to get to that page through the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never used this module, but try checking `/admin/config/media/image-styles` perhaps the module has an image style. If so, all you have to do is edit it and change it to your liking.

**Side Note:** You can also get there by clicking configuration, then under media click on Image Styles.

As you wrote in a comment:

> Editing the node_gallery_thumbnail style to replace the "Scale and crop" effect with a "Scale" with the same numbers for width and height did the trick.